# Delete redundant [microsoft-dynamics] tags

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

***Note:*** The question has been revised since Mokubai posted the comment below.  It originally looked like all of the [microsoft-dynamics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics) tags referred just to CRM, and the question suggested synonomizing them.  After the comment, additional research showed that it is a collection of different products and we have questions on three of them.  The tags have been cleaned up and the question has been revised to reflect treating the products separately, with no "manufacturer tag" decorating the questions.

Microsoft Dynamics is a suite of applications (CRM, NAV, and AX, represented by questions here, as well as GP, SL, and C5 with no questions).  CRM has a dedicated tag [dynamics-crm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm) (31 questions).

The [microsoft-dynamics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics) tag (originally 20 questions), is essentially a meta tag.  It decorated many of the CRM questions as a redundant tag, and was used as a generic tag for other MS Dynamics apps.

I've gone ahead and created dedicated tags for NAV and AX ([dynamics-nav](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-nav) and [dynamics-ax](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-ax)).  At this point [microsoft-dynamics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics) is only used on 11 questions, all as redundant tags for [dynamics-crm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm).

I suggest deleting the [microsoft-dynamics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics) tag since it doesn't add value.

Comment: I saw this a few days ago and it seems Dynamics appears to include several programs. There is a CRM product as well as an ERP system. How sure are you that these are the same? If they are simply two faces of the exact same product then the synonym makes sense, otherwise we could do with removing [Microsoft-dynamics] and retagging to [dynamics-crm] or [dynamics-erp]... I dont know enough about the product(s) to be sure which way this should go.

Comment: @Mokubai, good catch. Microsoft Dynamics is actually a whole collection of applications, so that tag is close to a meta tag. It would be more appropriate to remove all of those tags and add tags as needed for the other relevant apps. I revised the question.

Comment: Navision/Dynamics NAV is a completely different product to CRM. It costs upwards of $100,000 when configured. The tags definitely should not be merged. I once worked at a large manufacturer that heavily used Navision and they spent on the order of £250,000 on it, all told. Plus maintenance contracts. The company writing code for them were laughing all the way to the bank. It's simply not the same beast.

Comment: @DannyBeckett, there was a related Meta question some years ago where it was debated whether any of these products were even on-topic here.  Now we've got around 40 questions on the different products.  But yeah, a little research after first posting the question showed that it's a collection of different products that should not be merged, which makes [microsoft-dynamics] essentially a meta tag that doesn't really add value.  That's why I created dedicated product tags and revised the question to suggest removing what is basically a "manufacturer tag".